# BaseAdapter get values from textView and sum it

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have a base adapter in which I put some values from database. I count some value in it, and store it to textView. 
So if my BaseAdapter in list has e.g. 14 items, I want to get all these calculated values and sum them, and display them before listView.
I create some code, but I think I did it wrong.
What is the best solution for that. 
This is my code where everything is happening.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_logs_listview);
        boolean sort = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("sort", false);
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewItem);
        final String place = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("keyPlace");
        dbHandler = new LogsDBHandler(this);
        ArrayList<Logs> logsList = sort ? dbHandler.getAllLogsByPlace() : dbHandler.getAllLogs(place);
        listAdapter = new LogsArrayAdapter(logsList);
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        //HERE I TRIED TO GET ALL VALUES FORM TEXTVIEW AND SUM THEM
        for( int i=0; i<listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = listAdapter.getView(i, null, null);
            TextView result = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.LogMassResult);
            double sum = result + Integer.parseInt(final_result.getText().toString());
            String final_sum = String.format("%.2f", sum);
            result.setText(final_sum);
        }
    }

private class LogsArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Logs> logsList;

    public LogsArrayAdapter(List<Logs> logsList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DisplayLogs.this);
        this.logsList = logsList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return logsList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return logsList.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return logsList.get(position).getId();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_logs, parent, false);
        }
        Logs log = logsList.get(position);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDiameter)).setText(log.getDiameter());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLength)).setText(log.getLength());
        double log_length, log_diameter, length, diameter, result;
        log_length = Integer.parseInt(log.getLength().toString());
        log_diameter = Integer.parseInt(log.getDiameter().toString());
        length = log_length / 100;
        diameter = log_diameter * log_diameter * 3.14159265;
        result = length * diameter / 40000;
        String final_result = String.format("%.2f", result);
        //FROM BELOW TEXTVIEW I WANT GET VALUES AND SUM THEM
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount)).setText(final_result);            
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need of extra for loop you can do it in your getView method when you are setting text to textview

Comment: You have the data source and you can use that

Comment: But I need it to be in front of list View. I have 2-3 variables to display first, then this getView method goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you move the logic for calculating the "result" to the Logs class?

Then you could set the textview like this:                `((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount)).setText(log.getResult());`

And the total :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_logs_listview);
    boolean sort = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("sort", false);
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewItem);
    final String place = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("keyPlace");
    dbHandler = new LogsDBHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Logs> logsList = sort ? dbHandler.getAllLogsByPlace() : dbHandler.getAllLogs(place);

    TextView result = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.LogMassResult);
    double sum = 0.0;
    for( int i=0; i<logs.size(); i++) {
        sum += logs.get(i).getResult();
    }
    result.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum));

    listAdapter = new LogsArrayAdapter(logsList);
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this would do what i need (maybe I'm wrong). 
I need display the sum of the results before listview.

Comment: what do you mean by "before listview"?

Comment: I updated screenshot how I need to made this. 
You'll see on top of the screen is a count of items in listView, and below is sum of log_masses. 
and then below that is listview with items, and each item has mass. 
i need to sum all item masses and display them in top of the screen if it is possible

Comment: The solution I gave you will work for that case. So basically in the listview you show the result for each item, and before even instantiate the listview you can get the total result and display it in the textview over the listview.

Comment: I'm not quite good in android and java, but i'm learning. So Could you be more specific where to put which part of code  you wrote? Didn't understood quite good.

Comment: Moved result calculation to "Logs" class. don't know why but something with the sum in onCreate method is wrong. I did it like this because logs was throwing an error. 
but now line withs sum+=  it says Invalid Double ""
`TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LogMassResult);
        double sum = 0.0;
        for( int i=0; i<logsList.size(); i++) {
            sum += logsList.get(i).getResult();
        }
        result.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum));`
this is how I create this method

Comment: The result should be a double and not a string. Dont add this line to the result calculation:  String final_result = String.format("%.2f", result);